# Check when a setting has been changed

Tags: hooks

New to WordPress plugin development and I am looking for a hook that will execute when a setting has been changed in the 'Admin Dashboard' > 'Settings pages'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`update_option`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/update_option/) hook can use used to run an action when an option value has changed:

```
function wpse_330204_option_updated( $option_name, $old_value, $new_value ) {
    if ( $option_name === 'name_of_option_you_want_to_check' ) {
        if ( $new_value !== $old_value  ) {
            // Value has changed, run code here.
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'update_option', 'wpse_330204_option_updated', 10, 3 );
```

Just replace `name_of_option_you_want_to_check` with the actual name of the option you're looking for. *Usually* this will be the same as the `name=""` attribute of the `<input>` or `<select>` element that's used the change the value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Jacob, is there a simple way to capture all option changes?

Comment: Just don't check for a specific option name and the hook will run for all options. So you'd remove lines 2 & 6 from the code in my answer.